# Unable to cancel coroutine started with viewModelScope

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I am launching coroutine inside init of a `viewModel` in Kotlin.
Coroutine listens for data in a loop, everything works fine but as the title suggests, I am unable to cancel that coroutine(or maybe viewmodel is not calling on cleared) as socked keeps connected.

```kotlin
// viewmodel
init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        connector()
    }
}

override fun onCleared() {
    viewModelScope.cancel()
    super.onCleared()
}

suspend fun connector() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
    //val socket : Socket
    try {
             // connect socket
             // listen in loop
    } catch (Exception e){//whocares}
```

Already tried calling `finish()` on backpressed of the activity (tried a fragment too).

Comment: Is your loop checking to see if the coroutine is canceled? Cancellation is cooperative in coroutines.

Comment: @CommonsWare how do i check? tried using 'while (coroutineContext.isActive)' , does not help, however, oncleared IS getting called

Comment: Coroutine cancellation is cooperational. You need to check `isActive` inside your loop, or straight out kill the socket if it's blocking the thread and coroutine won't reach next loop.

Comment: `isActive` should work, assuming you are actually checking it when you think you are. If you are blocking indefinitely on I/O, you will not be checking during those blocks. You might look at [Korio](https://github.com/korlibs/korio), which appears to have coroutines-friendly TCP socket I/O.

Comment: Tried killing the socket, it reaches catch block but when activity is relaunched, it is still stuck inside catch block (coroutine is still alive). Tried calling [coroutineContext.]cancel in catch block, still alive, only thing that kills it is when i force stop (or tap run again from android studio). Thats one persistent coroutine i must say.

Comment: you need not to handle cancellation manually in if you start a coroutine with viewmodelScope. All the coroutine in viewmodelScope will be cancelled automatically when oncleared() is called. For more info check this link https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/easy-coroutines-in-android-viewmodelscope-25bffb605471

Comment: It sounds like the library you are using for socket connection is blocking the whole thread. If this is the case, you won't be able to use cancellation with coroutines because they rely on non-blocking runs. If you forcibly terminate the use of a socket, it may just be that something in the background is still running in a blocking way and so cancellation won't be easily achieved. I would love to help you further but I think we need more source code at least to understand which library you are using for sockets and how you are listening in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

This should resolve your issue, assign the job to a variable then use it to cancel.

```
    var job : Job? = null

    // viewmodel
    init {
        job = viewModelScope.launch {
            connector()
        }
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        job?.cancel()
        super.onCleared()
    }

    suspend fun connector() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        //val socket : Socket
        try {
                 // connect socket
                 // listen in loop
        } ca
```

Comment: coroutine can by invoking cancel() either on scope or job

Answer (score 0):

Cancellation in coroutine has to be cooperative. i.e your code should check the coroutine state.
In your socket connection, you should check `isActive` or `ensureActive()`
at least whenever any of the callbacks are invoked before proceeding further.
The ideal solution would be to manually close the socket connector since there is no guarantee that any of the callbacks. will be invoked. You can also try with `suspendCancellableCoroutine`

Answer (score -1):

You may do it by launching a NamedCoroutine as follows

```
val job =  viewModelScope.launch(CoroutineName("Name")) {}
```

you can put this job in

```
private val coroutineMap = mutableMapOf<String, Job>()
```

if you want to cancel it

```
val job = coroutineMap[coroutineName]
        job?.cancel()
        coroutineMap.remove(coroutineName)
```